# Cannot SSH to my AWS Linux instance after rebooting it

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services

In the AWS management console, I stopped a Linux instance.  Then I restarted it.  I tried to reconnect via Putty.  My putty session has an "Auto-login username" set and a private key for SSH authentication set.  AWS's DHCP gave my instance a new IP address upon rebooting.  So I changed the IP address in Putty.  When I try to connect via Putty I get this error:

"Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)"

How do I connect via Putty to my Linux instance?  I was able to connect fine before I rebooted it using AWS.  I tried using a different user.  But I don't even get to the password prompt.  It says "Server refused our key."

Comment: You could read this question: http://superuser.com/questions/421997/what-is-a-ssh-key-fingerprint-and-how-is-it-generated
It might be that, due to the ip address change, your machine's fingerprint also changed, which could cause the issue with Putty.

Comment: How do I generate a new .pem file (assuming the above applies to my situation)?

Answer (score 0):

You must specify SSH key in the putty for that server, attach key in the putty's left menu -> SSH->Auth->Private key file for authentication->Browse

Comment: I did what you described to reproduce the problem.  Does it need a new SSH key after a reboot happens?